# Edit multiple files as tabs by vim *txt

Tags: vim

When

```
vim *txt #1
```

vim allows to edit multiple files with extension txt.
Notwithstanding that this is an extremely useful functionality, I find it more easier to edit multiple files in tabs viz. tabedit.

Is there a way to port `#1` command to `tabedit` so that all the files are opened as tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `-p` option:

```
vim -p *txt
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can't accept answer before 10 minutes :).

Comment: More like "exactly what I was *waiting* for".